# question about universal sets of real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Suppose that $ A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \lt -5 \text{ or } x \ge 3\}$ and $B =\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -7 \lt x \le 3\} $. Find $(A \cup B)^c$.

I figured it to be $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \le -7 \text{ or } x \gt 3 \}$.

Did I calculate it right? Can you push me in the right direction?

Comment: Why "universal" sets?

Answer (score 5):

Just to make it graphical. I hope it helps:

[image]

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay, that does make sense now. I should have done that in the first place. So if the compliment of (A u B) is an empty set.

Comment: Yes, indeed, Max!

Comment: Nice picture. Too bad you forgot the complement sign...Still +1.

Comment: Well then the compliment would still be an empty set...

Comment: @julien: Yes the finial conclusion needs a $c$ as its power. Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$A\cup B = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x \in A \;\text{ or }\;\; x \in B \}$$

$$A\cup B = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid  x \lt -5 \;\;\text{or}\;\;x \geq 3\;\;\text{or}\;\; -7 \lt x \le 3\} = \mathbb R$$

So $$(A \cup B)^c = \mathbb R\setminus(A\cup B) = \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb R = \varnothing$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, $x\in A\cup B$ if and only if it is in either one; and it is in the complement if and only if it is not in neither.

What does it mean that $x$ is not in $A$ and not in $B$? It means that $-5\leq x<3$, and either $x<-7$ or $3<x$. Is there such $x$?